# How do i delete a printed text in python and replace it with another text

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am kind of bad at all this programming stuff and i need help.

I want my code to print something like hello world and then after lets say 1 second
delete that text and replace it with how are you?
I have tried various thing like 'clear' and '/b' but nothing is working, if you can help that would be amazing.

```
import time
print('hello world')
time.sleep(3)
#The text deleting code here...
print('how are you?')
```

Comment: In which environment you're running the code?

Comment: Python Idle is what i'm using.

Comment: If your gonna ask the version as well it is 3.6.2

Answer (score 1):

Use `end` parameter of [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print). By default, it's assigned `\n`. Instead, use a carriage return which is used to move the carriage back to the left side (beginning) of the current line.

```
import time
print('hello world', end='\r')
time.sleep(3)
#The text deleting code here...
print('how are you?')
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution but when i ran it in Idle it didn't work

Comment: Unfortunately, Python idle does not support `\r`. Read about it [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue23220). You could run this code on command prompt and get desired output.